# Change default scrollbar scrollposition in an html div

Tags: jquery, html, css

Is it possible to change starting scrollposition of 'scrollbar' by css or jQuery

[See the demo](http://jsfiddle.net/s3f6s7ub/1/) 
- div.container scroll until active element item(blue color) is shown as the topmost element in the div.

**Note** : I dont need jQuery 'content scroll' plugin

```
<div class="container">
    <ul class="content">
        <li>1</li>
        <li>2</li>
        <li>3</li>
        <li>4</li>
        <li class="active">5 active</li>
        <li>6</li>
        <li>7</li>
        <li>8</li>
        <li>9</li>
        <li>10</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: What are you asking here? to stop the scroll once the blue element is on top? to auto scroll to the blue element? a click event to scroll to the blue element?

Comment: I want to that blue element show is on top - not auto scroll @atmd

Answer (score 5, accepted):

apply the `scrollTop()` this way:

```
$('.container').scrollTop($('.content').find('.active').position().top);
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/s3f6s7ub/2/)

---

If you want it animated way use `.scrollTop()` with `.animate()`:

```
$('.container').animate({
    scrollTop:$('.content').find('.active').position().top
});
```

[Demo with animate.](http://jsfiddle.net/s3f6s7ub/3/)

Comment: Woowww simple and super answer , I was expecting this , I thought there is no syntax in jQuery for this :P , Tanks :) @jai

Comment: $('.container').animate({ scrollTop: $('.content').find('.active').position().top }, 'slow');

Comment: @Reza-S4 that is optional but if speed is needed then better to use numeric values.

Comment: @Jai that's true ! i want to sent the post and when i reloaded the page , i saw you edit your post ! so i commented it !!! ;)

Comment: @Reza-S4 ohh! better luck for next time.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function() {
    var t = $('li.active').position().top;
    $('div.container').scrollTop(t);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use scrolltop() to do it , such that the highlighted li comes at that top

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$( "div.container" ).scrollTop( 175 );
});
```

Comment: and when we don't know the offset of element, is it useful ?